# Select DOM element only with JS

Tags: javascript

I have a div that only contains data attribute, I want to select it from console with javascript

```
<div data-contents="true">
```

I tried `document.querySelectorAll('div > data-contents="true"')`

Doesn't work

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors Learn the basic selectors

Answer (score 2):

Add brackets

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-contents="true"]')
```